# How to copy image to clipboard from internet?

Tags: android, image, copy, clipboard

I am modifying the browser source code and I need to be able to copy an image to the clipboard from the internet. I can't seem to find out how to do it, and I know it's possible because I've seen it on a Note 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think android developer website explain this. Doesn't this will help you ?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: Well I've tried that, but I don't know how to use a URI with an image online.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the image via http, then place that onto the clipboard. It's the same in any platform.